Use external JS function in react and typescript file
In my react/next.js/typescript file, I load the YouTube iframe API in my useEffect like so
    useEffect(() => {
    const tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    const firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    const scriptContainer = document.head || document.documentElement;
    if (firstScriptTag) {
        scriptContainer.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
    }
    else {
        scriptContainer.appendChild(tag);
    }
}, []);

Then, later in the script, I attempt to use "YT", which is an object created by that YouTube iframe API script, like so
async function all_api_requests_finished(): Promise<void> {
num_vids = unshuffled_video_ids.length;
shuffled_video_ids = shuffle(unshuffled_video_ids); // Assuming shuffle function exists and returns the shuffled array

// Loading player
player = new YT.Player('player', {
    videoId: shuffled_video_ids[curr_vid], // The code of the initial video to play
    height: '390',
    width: '640',
    events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange,
        'onError': onPlayerError,
    }
});
player_loaded = true;

};
However, it won't let me build this next.js/react project, saying "Cannot find name 'YT'.". How do I make it know that I am loading the "YT" object from an external script such that it doesn't break on build?
Thank you in advance :) <3

You need to declare the object that youtube is creating for you so Next and React don't complain about unknown types.
If it's not attached to the window, which it doesn't look like it is the case, you would do that like this:
declare global {
  interface YT: {
  someMethod: (someParam: string) => void
  }
}

Or if it is automatically being attached to the window:
declare global {
    interface Window { YT: ...; }
}

The interface in those global declarations work the same as interfaces and types elsewhere in your app, but you might want to put this in a .d.ts file. That's not required anymore, but it makes life easier for some build processes.

I think I understand. So, do I basically just have to create a YT interface that defines all of the function I want to use in the file (even if it doesn't provide the implementation of each)?

Yup. You don't need to recreate everything that the YT object has, just the one's the you're accessing so typescript doesn't yell at you that it doesn't know what YT.someFunction or YT.someProperty is during the build process. Putting that in a .d.ts file will make it available everywhere, which used to be required for the global declarations, but now you can just stick it right in the file where you're using it, although the .d.ts approach will make sure that any build processes can find it. They should be able to anyways, but it's best to avoid the headache.

One thing to be aware of though, don't name your .d.ts file the same thing as a regular .ts file. If you have myComponent.ts, then definitely don't name it myComponent.d.ts.

Awesome man, thank you so much! One final question: how does one define something that I create with "new YT.player"? I keep trying a bunch of different stuff, but I still receive errors. Do I need to define a typescript class called "YT" that has member variables "videoId", "height", "width", and "events"? And then it'll simply be overwritten when the real YT class is loaded in by the external iframe js? Thanks again for all the help

For that you would have to do something similar. It sounds like YT is some sort of object or class, and YT.player is a class, given by the new keyword. Defining classes is slightly more tricky, but not much. The only difference is you have to account for the constructors, the methods that are part of the instance, and the methods (if any) that are available without calling 'new' (I forget the term... I'm kinda sleep deprived).

Typescript has some great docs here but I bet if you look around github, Google almost surely has the types for these classes available so you don't have to type them all out yourself, and then you'll get complete type safety while you're working with them too.
